# Copy to clipboard escape characters not remaining

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I have a winform file that contains a button, `copyBtn`, that when clicked should copy the contents of a listbox, `stringsListBox`, to the clipboard.

Using the implementation below, the escape character `\n` is not being recognized when I paste to a text document.

**Can I keep the escape character while copying to the clipboard?**

```
private void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string copyString = "";

    if(stringsListBox.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(string item in changesListbox.Items)
        {
            copyString += item + "\n";
        }
    }

    Clipboard.SetText(copyString);
}
```

If the listbox contains the following values: `(1, 2, 3, 4)` then when I paste to a text file the output is on one line:

```
1234
```

When I desire it to be one number per line:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Chances are, the `\n` is still there, but the text editor you're pasting into expects line breaks to be `\r\n`.

Comment: In addition to what @CodyGray said, try adding `Environment.NewLine` rather than `"\n"` to each item.

Comment: Just as a side note. `Clipboard.SetText` can sometimes fail (in Java at least, but I think this is a windows thing), for future reference if you notice issues you might need to make a `Task` that continually sets and checks the contents of the clipboard, returning once the clipboard contains the desired text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with text files, you need to use `\r\n`:

```
copyString += item + "\r\n";
```

Or better:

```
copyString += item + Environment.NewLine;
```

result in file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

From Docs : **Environment.NewLine Property**

> **Action: A property which returns the appropriate newline string for the given platform.
>
> **Returns: \r\n on Win32.